# Which HandlerInterceptorAdapter method should be implemented and used to clear ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thread-local

I have written an implementation of HandlerInterceptorAdapter. It is putting some request specific data in a ThreadLocal. Because threads are reused for new requests the data that was put in the ThreadLocal has to be removed when request is handled. Which HandlerInterceptorAdapter method should I implement to clear it? There are two options as I see it, postHandle and afterCompletion. I need that data in the ThreadLocal is guaranteed to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `afterCompletion`. It will be called on **any** outcome

> Callback after completion of request processing, that is, after rendering the view. Will be called on any outcome of handler execution, **thus allows for proper resource cleanup**.

**Reference**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

**Note**

- If you are going to return `false` from from `preHandle` you should clean up thread local in the pre handle itself because `false` means you have handled the response, as a result `postHanlde()` or `afterCompletion` will not be called